# It says can't convert type "void" to "string". I tried many different ways e.g. ToString and (string) but nothing seems to work

Tags: c#

This is a really basic program, but I'm stuck with it.

```
using System;

namespace Return
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           DecoratePlanet("Jupiter");
        }
        static string DecoratePlanet(string planet)
        {
          return Console.WriteLine($"*.*.* Welcome to {planet} *.*.*"); // here's the problem
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` doesn't return anything (it's `void`). Perhaps `DecoratePlanet` should also be `void` and then you can do away with the `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look into the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_), you´ll see that `Conole.WriteLine` does not return **anything** (=`void`). So you cannot use it in combination with a `return`-statement. Furthermore you don´t use the return-value of your method within the calling code, so it´ll be useless anyway - even **if** `Console.WriteLine` would return something.

Just omit the `return` and the return-type of your method:

```
static void DecoratePlanet(string planet)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"*.*.* Welcome to {planet} *.*.*");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in your DecoratePlanet method, you are trying to return the result of `Console.WriteLine` however `Console.WriteLine` has no return value (it's void), so instead your code could be

```
using System;

namespace Return
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           DecoratePlanet("Jupiter");
        }
        static void DecoratePlanet(string planet)
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"*.*.* Welcome to {planet} *.*.*"); // here's the problem
        }
    }
}
```

The only change is that I've changed the signature of DecoratePlanet to `void DecoratePlanet(string)` alternatively you could change the implementation of main and DecoratePlanet

```
using System;

namespace Return
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(DecoratePlanet("Jupiter"));
        }
        static string DecoratePlanet(string planet)
        {
          return $"*.*.* Welcome to {planet} *.*.*"; // here's the problem
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd prefer the latter because the DecoratePlanet can be used in more scenarios (not only for printing the string) and the name fits better. It does indeed decorate the string, it doesn't print a decorated string as in the previous implementation